# Crash when getting user input java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

For some reason my program is crashing when I am trying to get a user Input for a program I am writing. My class with my main in it looks like this.

```
package myQuiz;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class QuizApp {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String filename;
    System.out.print("Enter a filename: ");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    filename = sc.nextLine();
    sc.close();

    Quiz theQuiz = new Quiz(filename);

    theQuiz.testingFunction();
   }
}
```

Everything works up until I call the testingFunction and inside of it I ask for user input. This is what the testingFunction looks like and part of the Quiz class

```
package myQuiz;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Quiz {

private ArrayList<Question> questions = new ArrayList<Question>();
private String fileName;
private boolean fileIsValid;
private int correct;
private int incorrect;

public Quiz(String theFile){
    fileName = theFile;
    fileIsValid = false;
    correct = 0;
    incorrect = 0;
    loadQuestions(fileName);
}

public void testingFunction(){

        System.out.println("Enter: ");
        String input = "";
        Scanner as = new Scanner(System.in);
        input = as.nextLine();
        as.close();

        if(questions.get(0).checkAnswer(input) == true)
            System.out.println("True");
        else
            System.out.println("False");

   }
}
```

The error says this.

`Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)
    at myQuiz.Quiz.testingFunction(Quiz.java:41)
    at myQuiz.QuizApp.main(QuizApp.java:15)`

Line 41 is `input = as.nectLine();`
Line 15 is `theQuiz.testingFunction();`

Anybody know what's causing this to crash? Everything else works perfectly fine.
Those are the only two spots I am getting user input so far.

Comment: [Java Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()) and it says *NoSuchElementException - if no line was found*

Comment: You're closing the scanner. That closes System.in. Then you try to read from System.in again. But it's closed. Don't close scanners reading from System.in.

Comment: So how should I get user input?

Comment: You should also call `sc.hasNextLine()` before `sc.nextLine()`.

Comment: If I don't close it, eclipse flags that as a warning. And the ``sc.hasNextLine()`` didn't help, still crashes

Comment: @Programmer, then close it when your program ends, rather than in the middle.

Comment: You can only close the Scanner once because it will close `System.in` with it. This stream can't be open again later, it is generated by the JVM (basicly). So only close the Scanner at the end of the process, so a instance variable Scanner would be bettter